# Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Integer'

Tags: haskell

Código haskell:

```
bin2dec::[Integer]->Integer
bin2dec (h:[]) = h
bin2dec (h:t) = h*(2^length(t))+bin2dec(t)

bin2frac :: ([Integer], [Integer]) -> Double
bin2frac(x,y) = fromDouble(bin2dec(x)) * 10 ^ bin2dec(y)
```

Objetivo:

Definir uma função recursiva que recebe uma tupla com dois valores binários
representando, respectivamente, a mantissa e o expoente de um número e
retorna o correspondente fracionário decimal.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: @Patrick acho que é o erro no título: `Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Integer'`, deve ser isso.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei de onde vem essa função `fromDouble`, mas o problema sem ela é que `bin2dec algumaCoisa` retorna um `Integer`. É preciso usar a função `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`:

```
bin2dec :: [Integer] -> Integer
bin2dec (h:[]) = h
bin2dec (h:t)  = h * (2 ^ length t) + bin2dec t

bin2frac :: ([Integer], [Integer]) -> Double
bin2frac (x, y) = fromInteger $ (bin2dec x * 10) ^ bin2dec y
```

Não revisei a lógica do seu código.